# jQuery animation goes in but doesn't go back

Tags: jquery, animation, navbar

I'm trying to make a logo appear in a navbar when you scroll over it and it get fixed to the top of the page and it seems to work fine, but when trying to reverse the animation, it behaves weirdly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (scroll > 174) {
            $('#navbar').css({"position":"fixed","top":"0","margin-top":"0"});
            $('section').css({"margin-top":"48px"});
            $('#logo_navbar').animate({"opacity": "1","width": "114px"}, 200);
        } else {
            $('#navbar').css({"position":"relative","margin-top":"-4px"});
            $('section').css({"margin-top":"0"});
            $('#logo_navbar').css({"opacity": "0","width": "0px"});
        }
    });
});
```

(The problem is with the #logo_navbar animation).

Here's a demo:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nkgcqbf/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It behaves weirdly? What do you mean by that? I believe you refer to the logo hiding too fast, if that's the case, then your problem is that you are not performing an animation in your else statement, should be as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).scroll(function () {
         var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
         if (scroll > 174) {
             $('#navbar').css({
                 "position": "fixed",
                 "top": "0",
                 "margin-top": "0"
             });
             $('section').css({
                 "margin-top": "48px"
             });
             $('#logo_navbar').animate({
                 "opacity": "1",
                 "width": "114px"
             }, 200);
         } else {
             $('#navbar').css({
                 "position": "relative",
                 "margin-top": "-4px"
             });
             $('section').css({
                 "margin-top": "0"
             });
             $('#logo_navbar').stop().animate({
                 "opacity": "0",
                 "width": "0px"
             }, 200);
         }
     });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6nkgcqbf/1/

Comment: You'll need to use .stop() like so... $('#logo_navbar').stop().animate({"opacity": "0","width": "0px"}, 300);

Comment: You are right, in case the animation is running when the user scrolls up. Edited. Thanks!

Comment: With weirdly I meant that after you scroll down and it shows the logo, it doesn't reverse when scrolling up. Using .stop() fixed it and now it works perfectly. Much appreciated.